# \newenvironment without using environ package

Tags: environments

I want to create a new environment without using the environ package, which conflicts with other packages that I have. I can create the command like this when using environ package.

```
\NewEnviron{MyCommand}{\foo{\BODY}}
```

and then envoke \foo{content} using

```
\begin{MyCommand} content \end{MyCommand}
```

Instead of

```
\foo{content}
```

Is there a way to create the same environment without using the environ package? Thanks

Comment: What conflict? I know of none.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to reverse engineer what you can doing based on incomplete information.

Comment: LaTeX defines a command `\newenvironment{<env. name>}{<code at begin>}{<code at end>}`. Is that sufficient for your use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems unlikely that `NewEnviron` clashes with any other definition as it has a very self contained definition, however there are several alternatives, for example if you have a recent release of the `xparse` package then the `b` argument type is available to capture an environment body.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyCommand}{b}{\fbox{#1}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{MyCommand}content\end{MyCommand}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This worked.  Also package \newenviron worked as well.  I am sorry if my question was less than clear.  I am somewhat new to Latex.